# JLabel as a clickable hyperlink

Tags: java, swing

I have taken one JFrame in which we have shown the information about our firm 
there is one information(label) like:

website: www.samteksystems.com 
I want that whenever I click on www.samteksystems.com it should display that website.
Please help me in this.

Comment: Perhaps you want to add a MouseListener to the JLabel that holds the information, and in this MouseListener's mousePressed method, you would start the default browser and direct it to your page.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels - perhaps this should have been posted as an answer instead of a comment!

Answer (score 4):

You can add a mouseListener to the label, and in the mouseReleased() method, you could use Desktop.browse() to visit the URL.